# "Embed" ClojureScript app into existing AngularJS SPA

Tags: angularjs, clojure, clojurescript

I'm petty new to ClojureScript, even if I have some experience in Clojure. I'm developing a new feature for an existing AngularJS application and I would like to use ClojureScript.
I would like to know if someone has some experience doing this, in particular: how to make ClojureScript and Angular talk to each other? For example, inside an angular controller, how can I access ClojureScript data and functions? And even more important, inside my ClojureScript app, how can I access Angular data and functions?